# Managing multiple non-document windows in Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have an app that needs to open and track multiple windows. New windows are created in response to a **File > New Window** command, and are created programmatically (no storyboards or XIBs).

There are no documents involved, so I don't want any of the file actions, modified state tracking, or other document-related features that come with a Document-based application from Xcode. I *do* want the ability to cascade new windows, and to remember the size and position of all open windows so they can be restored when the app launches.

Tracking the open windows is easy enough and there are plenty of examples out there. I can set an autosave name, but that only seems to work on the first window that gets created. [NSWindowController.shouldCascadeWindows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1528177-shouldcascadewindows?language=objc) only seems to work with Document-based apps.

Do I have to implement cascading and geometry persistence myself, or is there some way to hook into those features? Thanks!

Comment: You were right that NSWindowController in showWindow: checks existing  documentcontroller. However if you override showWindow with some custom code you get the same behaviour. Use methods setFrameTopLeftPoint: and cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:. shouldCascadeWindows should be YES if you restore window from coder (works auto without nsdocumentcontroller).

Comment: Is this a fixed number fo windows or is the user opening new windows? How do you instantiate a new window (storyboard, xib)? Are the windows restored when the app launches?

Comment: I updated the question with that information.

Comment: Take a look at `cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:`. Are the windows `restorable`?